# AttributeError: 'Order' object has no attribute 'shipping'

Tags: python, django, python-3.9

Learning Django with [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woORrr3QNh8&list=PL-51WBLyFTg0omnamUjL1TCVov7yDTRng&index=22).

In the end of lesson I have error:

> AttributeError: 'Order' object has no attribute 'shipping'.

I can't understand what's wrong.

[image: Error]

Error in PyCharm Terminal

[image: Error in PyCharm Terminal]

I understand that `Order` must have `shipping` attribute, but cant find where exactly looking that.

Sorry for bad english.

My project files:

[image: project]

`checkout.html`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url



class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_addet = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total

class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

`views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
import json
import datetime
from .models import *


def store(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0, 'shipping':False}
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products':products, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)

def cart(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0, 'shipping':False}
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    context = {'items':items, 'order':order, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)

def checkout(request):

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0, 'shipping':False}
        cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    context = {'items':items, 'order':order, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)


def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']

    print('Action', action)
    print('productId', productId)


    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)

    orderItem.save()

    if orderItem.quantity <=0:
        orderItem.delete()

    return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)


def processOrder(request):
    transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    data = json.loads(request.body)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        total = float(data['form']['total'])
        order.transaction_id = transaction_id

        if total == float(order.get_cart_total):
            order.complete = True
        order.save()

        if order.shipping == True:
            ShippingAddress.objects.create(
                customer=customer,
                order=order,
                address=data['shipping']['address'],    #порядок как в models
                city=data['shipping']['city'],
                state=data['shipping']['state'],
                zipcode=data['shipping']['zipcode'],
            )

    else:
        print('User is not logged in...')
    return JsonResponse('Payment complete!', safe=False)
```

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=False)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url



class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_addet = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total

class ShippingAddress(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

`urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [

   path('', views.store, name="store"),
   path('cart/', views.cart, name="cart"),
   path('checkout/', views.checkout, name="checkout"),

   path('update_item/', views.updateItem, name="update_item"),
   path('process_order/', views.processOrder, name="process_order"),
]
```

I reviewed the lesson several times, code seems to be without mistakes.

Comment: share error which is shown in the terminal

Comment: Topic is error from PyCharm terminal:  AttributeError: 'Order' object has no attribute 'shipping'

Comment: in your `Order` model there should be a field named `shipping` this is what the code require

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Server side error**

The error is because you didn't declared `shipping` variable in your Orders model.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    shipping = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total
```

Go to models file and update the Order class with above code.

**client side**

While making API request set the header `Content-Type` to `text/html`.

Because the API is responding HTML file not json.

That's why you have an error in browser.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's work. But I didnt changed Content-Type for now. And first time forget about migrations. I cant understand why in lesson wasnt shipping attribute, maybe cos its 2 years old video and old python version.

Answer (score 0):

in `Order` model there should be a field named `shipping`  which is require in the `processorder` view.

just add below field in `Order` model

`shipping = models.BooleanField(default=False)`

since you want ot hide it , then a `property` need to be added not the db field

so your model should look like this

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    date_ordered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    transaction_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    
    @property
    def shipping(self):
        shipping = False
        # add shipping logic here
        return shipping

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    @property
    def get_cart_total(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.get_total for item in orderitems])
        return total

    @property
    def get_cart_items(self):
        orderitems = self.orderitem_set.all()
        total = sum([item.quantity for item in orderitems])
        return total
```

follow the tutorial a little more, you will be able to grasp the solution.

Comment: Thanks, your method fixed error, but hide shipping for logged in user at all.

Comment: @Artem added the change